# Extract a large .tar.gz file and upload about 10 csv to database

Tags: php, api, csv, cron, server-configuration

From Crunchbase I am downloading a .tar.gz file of about 350MB that contains 16 csv  of size more then 1.5GB which I need to insert in database tables. 
link to crunchbase docs:
[Daily CSV Export](https://data.crunchbase.com/docs/daily-csv-export)
I have made a cron file in PHP that runs and do that work for me. 
The issue I am having is when I run that script on server it throws 504 error. 
How can I resolve this error and is it good to process this big data on server through cron-job?

Comment: No it isn't. Use bash (wget for example) to download files, and then run the insert queries directly in bash. You get the 504 because you're server didn't respond for a very long time (of course, it was working).

Comment: I am not so aware about Bash but according to my knowledge I will have to do all the things manually for which I have written a script. LIKE download file, extract it , insert in to db and delete all files.I need to update data everyday so I was thinking just running a cron-job would do that.

Comment: You probably can use a cronjob and php may work with that, but it's not a good way to go. And bash isn't hard to learn at all.

Comment: PHP CLI should work ok - it may not be quite as efficient as bash, but it should work. Where is the 504 error coming from exactly?

Comment: When I am trying to download .tar.gz file.